# Meaning of a Poisson's equation being solved over a rectangle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, poissons-equation

I've a problem regarding the Poisson's equation:

> The version of the Poisson's equation being solved here is
>
> $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} u(x, y) = f(x, y)$$
>
> $$u(x, y) = g(x, y) \text{ on $\partial D$}$$
>
> **over the rectangle $$0 \leq x \leq 1\\0 \leq y \leq 1\\$$**

What's the meaning of "a Poisson's equation being solved over a rectangle"?

Answer (score 1):

The rectangle is the domain of your equations, so where you have the boundary of D, D is your rectangle.

Comment: yeah exactly. If you plotted those values on a graph youd get a rectangle. (well technically a square but I mean its a special case!)